# dynamic binding in SwiftUI ForEach for a field

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

For an abstract input field that should be rendered in `ForEach`, given a struct,

```
struct InputFieldCustom: Identifiable, Hashable {

    let id = UUID()
    let placeholder: String
    let imageResourceName: String
    var storage: String = "email"
}
```

I would like to set text binding from `storage` var of this struct, is that possible by referencing a label?

```
ForEach(inputFields, id: \.self) { inputStruct in
    TextField(inputStruct.placeholder, text: \.$storage)
}
```

(on the top of the view I have)

`@State private var email = "") ?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible variant

```
ForEach(Array(inputFields.enumerated()), id: \.1) { index, inputStruct in
    TextField(inputStruct.placeholder, text: self.$inputFields[index].storage)
}
```